# How to express joint conditional probability with multiple conditions

Tags: conditional-probability, joint-distribution

I want to express the joint probability of $\Phi_A$ and $\Phi_B$: $p(\Phi_A, \Phi_B)$  conditioned that $\Phi_A$ and $\Phi_B$ are both greater than some value C.  How would I express this mathematically?  I guess my intuition says:

$p(\Phi_A, \Phi_B | \bf{\Phi} >C)$

Is this correct? Is there a better way to express this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it is your choice which notation to use, but you certainly can just use logical operators:

$p(\Phi_A, \Phi_B \; |\; \Phi_A>C \,\cap \Phi_B > C)$

Your current notation is not clear as $\Phi$ is not defined and not obvious what it means.